# How to downgrade OpenSSL from 1.1.1 to 1.0.2? Debian 10

Tags: debian, openssl

I need 1.0.2 version of libssl, does somebody know how to downgrade from the newest 1.1.1 or download directly that version?

Comment: If you want to support old ciphers, it is better to change the cipersuite configuration, for instance by setting "CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1" in "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you’re on `amd64`, you can download it from the Debian 9 repositories and install it:

```
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2u-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.2_1.0.2u-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
```

This will install `libssl` 1.0.2 *alongside* 1.1.1, and software built against either will work. You shouldn’t try removing 1.1.1.

If you want to compile software looking for version 1.0.2, you‘ll need the development package too:

```
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2u-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2u-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
```

`openssl` is separate, and you should use the latest version:

```
sudo apt install openssl
```